# SAS 9.3. Find two-tailed P-Value using T-Statistic

Tags: sas

is there a function in SAS that I can use to find a two-tailed P-value?

The information I have is the T-statistic (.551447) and the degrees of freedom (25)

Using a free web calculator, I know that the P-Value, given this information:
P-Value (Two tailed) = .5862

I've tried looking up possible functions like tinv() but was not quite successful in finding the correct value I am looking for. Please help, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need PROBT() function. And p-value will be calculated like this:

```
data _null_;
  x=.551447;
  df=25;
  p=(1-probt(abs(x),df))*2;
  put p=;
run;
```

Result in log:

```
p=0.5862228899
```